# Express.js - How to create a helper function with built in response object

Tags: express

I create a rest API in express, and I want to create a helper to make every response have the same object.
I have a following code in typescript

```js
abstract class BaseService {
...
  protected sendOK(res: Response, msg?: string | object): object {
    res.status(200);
    return res.send({
      status: "success",
      message: msg
    })
  }
...
}

class Device extends BaseService {
...
  public create = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    ...
    return this.sendOK(res, msg)
  }
...
}
```

the code above is working, but what I'm asking is there any way to call `this.sendOK(msg)` without passing the `res` object?

Comment: You  either have to pass the `res` object or you have to have previously saved it in the instance data of the object.  But, since I doubt you want to have a separate Device object for every new request.  You probably don't want to store it in the instance datga because if you store the `res` object in the object, then you have to have a separate object for every request so multiple requests in flight at the same time don't conflict with one another.  It's a helper that operates on the `res` object so it makes sense to me that you'd pass it the `res` object to use.

Comment: Yes, I don't want a separate response. So it means if I instantiate the res object in the helper, it will create another res object, right?

Comment: You can't instantiate a response object yourself.  It comes from the server.  The server creates a new response object for each incoming request.  You have to use the one the server creates for you for each request.

Comment: I'm wondering if maybe you should extend the existing response object.  In some middleware, you could add your helper methods to the existing response object.  Then, you would just do `res.create()`.

Comment: Ooh i see, could you tell me how to extend the existing response object?